# Initial values of memory and previous block output in LSTM?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, rnn, lstm

I am trying to understand LSTM and reading [colah blog](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) , As LSTM structure looks like this :

[image]

So LSTM takes three inputs:

- Input vector
- Memory from previous block
- Output from previous block

and return :

- memory from current block
- output from current block

which will become previous memory and previous block output for next state ,

My confusion is what is the initial values of ct-1 ( memory from previous block) and ht-1 ( hidden output from previous block) , since there is no previous block then what are initial values ?

Answer (score 1):

Either you use a zero vector state for both (most commonly used), or you can use other approaches such as described in [this](https://r2rt.com/non-zero-initial-states-for-recurrent-neural-networks.html) article.

I have personally always used zero vectors.